# Accessing appsettings.json Settings Outside Controllers or Razor Components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following class:

```cs
public class MongoDBService
{
    private String ConnectionString;

    private String DatabaseName;

    private readonly MongoClient _Client;
    public MongoDBService()
    {
        _Client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);
    }

    public IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>()
    {
        return _Client.GetDatabase(DatabaseName).GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

I also have the following in appsettings.json:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "MongoDBService": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "Test"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

How can I get the ConnectionString and DatabaseName values from appsettings.json into the constructor of my MongoDBService class? I can only find examples of how to use appsettings.json in controllers. I need settings from appsettings.json in this class which can be initiated literally anywhere in my project.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET Core provides an easy way to access settings via dependency injection and the options pattern - [REF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

**1.**

You have to define a `MongoDbServiceSettings` class with properties you want read from the `appsettings.json`

```
 public class MongoDbServiceSettings
 {
     public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

     public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
 }
```

**2.**

Then you need to register the configuration in your `Startup.cs`

`services.Configure<MongoDbServiceSettings>(configuration.GetSection("MongoDBService"))`

You will need the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.Configuration` package for that.

**3.**

After that you can inject you settings in your `MongoDBService` class (or wherever you need) in the constructor:

```
public class MongoDBService
{
     private readonly MongoDbServiceSettings _mongoDbSettings;
     private readonly MongoClient _Client;

     public MongoDBService(IOptions<MongoDbServiceSettings> mongoDbSettings)
     {
         _mongoDbSettings = mongoDbSettings.Value;
         _Client = new MongoClient(_mongoDbSettings.ConnectionString);
     }

     //rest of class
 }
```

Comment: Hey Plamen, nice one! My only issue now is that when I want to initiate a new MongoDBService() instance, it throws an exception as no argument is passed for IOptions<MongoDBServiceSettings>

Comment: Yes, that happens because you're not using your `MongoDBService` as a dependency. You could register it in your `Startup.cs` and pass it to the constructors of the classes you're using it in. You can register it like this: `services.AddTransient(typeof(MongoDBService))`